# Create simple hit counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def show
   Bottle.increment_counter :views, @bottle
end
```

Works quite well, however if the same person views it over and over again it keeps incrementing. How should I go about fixing this so only unique hits increment it?

Should I have an `ip` model and make my Bottle  model `have_many` ips,the ips being that of the people who visited it? And then, do *something* this? (I'd extract it out into a class method but this is just to show you):

```
def show
   if !@bottle.ips.include?(request.remote_ip)
       Bottle.increment_counter :views, @bottle
       Ip.create(bottle_id: @bottle, ip: request.remote_ip )
   end
end
```

I think the above would work, **but wouldn't this result in the database filling up very, very quickly? Or is this a practise, regardless? If this isn't a practise, how could I do the same with cookies somehow? What would be the structure of the cookie?**

Also, I know there are a bunch of hit counter gems but I want to do this myself (with your help :P)

Answer (score 2):

The thing about requesting the IP address is that you could have the same IP address for everyone in the same network (that's just the IP address you might see) even though internally in their network, they each obviously have their own IP address.

...in your controller

```
def show
  # see if they already have a cookie, if so
  # it will create a cookie with the Hit id you created
  if cookies.has_key?(:unique_hit_key)
    hit = Hit.find(cookies[:unique_hit_key])
    hit.count = hit.count.to_i+1
    hit.save
  else
    cookies[:unique_hit_key] = {
      :value => Hit.create(count: 1).id,
      :expires => 1.year.from_now,
      :domain => 'domain.com'
    }
  end
end
```

This doesn't track the IP, but you really don't need it.  This will keep a count of all visitors by their cookie that you set if you don't see one.  This is assuming loosely that you don't have to worry about people wiping out their cookies.  If you need better control over this, you need to probably track via logins, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would set it in a cookie, you can review how to do so [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).  This also allows flexibility so if you want to track user views if they view it once a week or whatever.